# Ionic + AngularJs custom css transition not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-transitions, ionic-framework

I'm currently writing an Ionic + AngularJS app.

On a specific page I want show / hide a div based on swiping. I have this behaviour working but as you can see in the gif below there is a problem when the div moves from the bottom of the page. When you swipe up, the div moves to the top and then extends down. I'm looking for it to move from the bottom in one motion.

I'm setting a class on the div using `ng-class`

`<div on-swipe-up="myvar='sideBar'" on-swipe-down="myvar=''" class="sideBarBase" ng-class="myvar">`

My CSS looks like:

```
.sideBarBase {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height: 15%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: .9;
    padding: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: .6s;}

.sideBar {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    top:0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I fixed this was instead of changing between `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` I now just change the height between `height: 10%` and `height: 100%` maintaining the `bottom: 0`

The CSS in full now looks like:

```
.sideBarBase {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height: 10%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: .9;
    padding: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: .6s;
}

.sideBar {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```